# How to implement a boolean method that accepts an integer as parameter?

Tags: java, methods, boolean

I have done my research but can't find the solution for this.

Ok so this piece of code is supposed to have a method that accepts an integer and returns true or false depending upon the result of the evaluation. The main class contains a loop that generates random numbers which are passed to the method. then the method checks if the number is negative or positive and returns the result. For me everything looks quite right. But there must be something I'm not seeing since my program does not work. Any suggestions would be appreciate it.

```
public class isNegative {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        int negatives = 0;
        int positives = 0;
        int number = 0;
        boolean result = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)    {
            Random rand = new Random();
            number = rand.nextInt(201)-100;
            result = isNegative(number);
            if (result == false)    {
                positives += 1;
            } else  {
                negatives += 1;
            }
        }
        //boolean status = false;
        System.out.printf("Number of negatives: %i\n", negatives);
        System.out.printf("Number of positives: %i\n", positives);

    }


    public static boolean isNegative(int test)  {
        if (test <= 0)  {
            return true;
        } else  {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And "does not work" is defined as...?

Comment: why on earth are you creating 99 randoms when you could move that above the for loop and it wouldn't be a waste of memory

Comment: I agree with @EpicPandaForce. Also, I strongly recommend using a seed for the Random during debug. That way, you can do the same test several times in a row, rather than having different inputs every time.

Comment: by the way it's because 1.) you return `isNegative == true` even at 0 even though `0` is not a negative number, and 2.) because you should just use `System.out.println("Number of negatives: " + negatives);` and `System.out.println("Number of positives: " + positives);`.

Comment: technically you used `%i` instead of `%d` and I'm not even sure why you used `printf` in the first place

Comment: You need to define "Does not work".  There's nothing immediately obvious that would make your code fail to compile - although both comments by @EpicPandaForce are very much valid and would improve your code. The treatment of zeros might be frowned upon if this is an assignment (zero is neither negative or positive)

Comment: `System.out.println("Number of negatives: " + i);` the java compiler allows that

Comment: Probably that's what does not work means here - the %i is wrong in the printf statement and you have the syntax wrong on the `System.out.println(` - you don't use variables in the string and substitution there - just follow what's in @EpicPandaForce comment exactly

Comment: eclipse is giving me the error when I tried println. Also by "does not work" I mean i does not compile. I'm pretty new to Java, that is why I code my not look like a 20 year experienced programmer.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce was right. What I did is System.out.println("Number of negatives: " + negatives); and totally worked. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

You could tidy up your code but it does broadly what you might want it to do

```
public class IsNegative {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        int negatives = 0, nonNegatives = 0;
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 99; i++) {
            int number = rand.nextInt(201)-100;
            if (isNegative(number))
                negatives++;
            else
                nonNegatives++;
        }
        System.out.printf("Number of negatives: %d%n", negatives);
        System.out.printf("Number of non-negatives: %d%n", nonNegatives);
    }

    public static boolean isNegative(int test)  {
        return test < 0;
    }
}
```

Note: `0` is not a negative or positive number.

BTW: There is no `%i`, most likely you meant to use `%d` for decimal.

I suggest you read the [Formatter Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) if you want to know more on how to use the formatter.

Answer (score 0):

random.nextInt() can only generate values >=0
so if you want to gen -100 and +100 you should use something like this:

```
Random r = new Random();

public int rand(){
    int num=r.nextInt(10000);
    if(num>5000){
        return r.nextInt(100); 
    }else{
        return -r.nextInt(100);
    }
}
```

you can change and adjust possibility of getting negative numbers

Comment: `Random.nextInt(int)` only takes one int value and doesn't give negative numbers.